# Using API to collect tag information - data differences

Tags: support, api, tags

I am trying to get a list of the most popular tags on Stack Overflow.
According to the SO page, these are the most popular tags as of today:

[image]

The Python tag has 6690 questions asked this week alone.
When I use the Stack Exchange API page for the last 30 days, the most popular tag is wikidata-query-service with only 115:

[image]

Am I doing something wrong? Where are these discrepancies coming from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fromdate` and `todate` are not limiting the number of questions posted with that tag; rather, they are filters on the creation date *of the tag itself*. You're basically asking the API "what are the most popular tags created in the last 30 days", and the answer is [wikidata-query-service], [bonferroni], ...

I don't think it's (easily) possible to get a list of 'recently popular' tags from the API. You should try the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) instead.